# When is the supremum of a function on a subset equal to the supremum on a set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous, real function on a set $X$. Suppose the set $D \subset X$ is dense in $X$, and the set $S \subset X$ is closed and has empty interior, i.e. it is nowhere dense. Moreover, $S\cap D$ is nonempty.

Are there any known conditions for when $\sup(f(S))=\sup(f(S\cap D))$?

I would like to treat $X$ as a general topological space, but feel free to make any assumptions you need.

Comment: @Renard not in general, but I’d still be interested in a proof under the assumption that D is countable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions allow $S\cap D$ to be a singleton, which isn’t much better than allowing $S$ and $D$ to be disjoint; you’ll need a lot more interaction between $S$ and $D$ to get equality of the suprema. Suppose, in fact, that $S\cap D$ is not dense in $S$, and let $H=\operatorname{cl}(S\cap D)\subsetneqq S$. Fix $p\in S\setminus H$. If $X$ is Tikhonov, there is a continuous real-valued function $h:X\to[0,1]$ such that $h(p)=1$ and $h[H]=\{0\}$; clearly $\sup h[S]=1>0=\sup h[S\cap D]$.

This shows that if $X$ is at all nice in terms of the existence of real-valued functions, you’ll need $S\cap D$ to be dense in $S$, and in that case you do of course get equality of the suprema.

Comment: Since $S$ has empty interior, this implies that we must have that $S \subset D$ right? This is what I’m afraid of...

Comment: @Tyler6: No, it doesn’t. If $S$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set, for instance, the set of endpoints of the deleted intervals is a dense subset of $S$, and by a cardinality argument $D\subsetneqq S$.

Comment: If $D$ is closed, then must it be that $S \subset D$? This is what I thought and what I'm hoping isn't the case.

Comment: @Tyler6: Yes, if you want the space to be at least Tikhonov: if $S\cap D$ dense in $S$, and $D$ is closed, then $D\supseteq S$. The only alternative that I can see would be to have some restrictions on the functions that you’re considering, but what they might be would depend pretty heavily on $S$ and $D$.

Comment: I see thank you! My space is Tikhonov, I will work on trying to appeal to my function in particular in that case.

Comment: @Tyler6: You’re welcome! And good luck with it!